# How can I display a Bootstrap popover with an html content from a GridView?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, popover

I have been at this for like two hours now trying various stuff. I can get the popover to display as just a basic title/content, but I haven't found a way to get it to work with HTML and Eval() as the content yet. This is what I'm working with:

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnViewRefDrDetails").popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $("#popover-content-wrapper").html();
        },
        title: function () {
            return $("#popover-title").html();
        },
        container: 'body'
    });
})
```

And the HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridTOC" runat="server"
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ref Dr" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewRefDrDetails" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ReferringName") %>' data-toggle="popover"
                                title="Popover Title" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return false" role="button" rel="popover">
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                            <%--this should be the template for the popover--%>
                            <div id="popover-content-wrapper" style="display: none;">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Provider Name:</b>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><%# Eval("ReferringName")%></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Provider Specialty:</b>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><%# Eval("ProviderSpecialty")%> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Practice Name:</b>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><%# Eval("PracticeName")%></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Practice Address:</b>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><%# Eval("PracticeAddress")%></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Practice City:</b>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><%# Eval("PracticeCity")%> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Practice State:</b>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><%# Eval("PracticeState")%> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Practice ZIP:</b>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><%# Eval("PracticeZip")%> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><b>Practice Phone:</b>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><%# Eval("PracticePhone")%> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div id="popover-title" style="display: none">
                                <%# Eval("ReferringName")%>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

When I click the LinkButton, nothing happens at all. No errors, just nothing. When I just hard code the popover's title and content it works fine. What do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the problem is that there are more than one `$("#popover-content-wrapper")`, because if it is in a `GridView`, I think is normal to have more than one row.

I have an example of how I implment this to show a larger `<img>` in a popover

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="imgSignature" runat="server"  
                data-img='<%# Eval("ImgBase64")  %>' 
                data-toggle="popover"
                ImageUrl='ViewLarger.jpg' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

$('img[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: function () {
        return '<img width="250px" src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />';
    }
});
```

As you can see, I save the information I want to pass to the popover in a `data-X` attribute in the trigger element, and in the JS function just place it when appropiate. In your case should be

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewRefDrDetails" 
                            data-toggle="popover"
                            data-ReferringName='<%# Eval("ReferringName")%>' 
                            data-ProviderSpecialty='<%# Eval("ProviderSpecialty")%>' >
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

$('a[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: function () {
        return '<table><tr><td>Provider Name' + $(this).data('ReferringName') + '</td></tr> etc...';
    }
});
```

Comment: I ended up using parts of your solution and changing the popover-content-wrapper to a class instead of an id, then just searching for the next instance of it with on the link's click event. Thanks for your help :)